# Concurrent parsing and filtering with unique_lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, mutex

I want to read an xml document, filter anything I don't want (the filtering is not part of the question) and then write back to cout or an ofstream.

However, the way I want to do this concurrently, is the following: Thread1 (parser) read the xml file, read one line (std::string line in my code) at a time, and then supply that line to thread2 whose only job is to filter that line. After it is finished, it supplies that line back to thread1, to write to output.

However, my program right now is not safe at all. First of all, sometimes thread2 is able to acquire the mutex first, and I get an error even if I do std::unique_lock locker(mu, defer_lock), or even I make thread2 wait for 100 ms: std::this_thread::sleepfor(100ms). I'm not sure how to make sure that the acquisition of the mutex is done by thread1 first.

A more important problem is that even if thread1 acquires the mutex first, I get an error at the line locker.unlock() of function2, right after my program has read the first line of the document. Searching for this error, it seems like I could be trying to unlock a mutex that is already unlocked. Shouldn't the initialization of unique_lock in function2 lock the mutex?

Finally, I think I might either be using the wrong resources, or that the structure of my program is wrong. Could I have some suggestions to make the code better?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>


std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cond;
bool checkThread1 = false;
bool checkThread2 = false;
std::string line;
bool checkIfEndOfFile = false;
//std::once_flag flag;


void function1()
{
std::ifstream in("example.xml");
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        locker.unlock();
        cond.notify_one();
        checkThread2 = !checkThread2;
        cond.wait(locker, []() {return checkThread1; });
    }
}

void function2()
{
std::string substring = "";
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
cond.wait(locker, []() {return checkThread2; });
std::string tmp2 = "";
std::string tmp1;
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    // Filter
}
locker.unlock();
cond.notify_one();
checkThread1 = !checkThread1;
}


int main()
{
std::thread parser(function1);
std::thread filterer(function2);
parser.join();
filterer.join();
}
```

Comment: someone might come up with a fix for your particular problem, but your code doesn't make lots of sense. First of all using threads here will not speed up anythiing, on the contrary: your main thread doesn't do anything and the other two threads have to wait for each other - that's the same effect as using just one thread. Second: this kind of problem has been solved before, usually by means of a thread-safe queue. (one thread pushes values onto it, other thread consumes them) resulting in much less code than what you have but much more correct (and working). Look it up and use it.

Comment: You are right that it doesn't optimize anything, my purpose for writing this is only educational. You propose the producer/consumer model, and that is what I'm trying to do. Only instead of a queue, there's a global string.

Comment: Well that is quite different: a queue can hold multiple strings but you have only one. Producer/consumer is typical for cases where producing data happens at a different rate than consuming it. So a queue works ok there, just because it can hold more than one string.